# Erro em declarações com Array

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Galera, estou com um erro que não consigo encontrar a solução.
Eu tenho duas hospedagens no mesmo local Hostgator, em uma hospedagem a minha aplicação está tudo certo e funcionando. Porém precisei migrar a aplicação para outro endereço, em outras palavras migrei para um Sub-dominio, até ai ok.

Depois que migrei percebi que estava dando erro na seguinte declaração:

```
$arr = [];
```

Então eu mudei a declaração para

```
$arr = array();
```

Desta maneira funcionou em partes, porém percebi que está dando erro neste tipo de declaração, por que?

Outro problema está sendo neste seguinte item:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /
```

Na linha deste erro está a seguinte declaração:

```
if(!empty($ClientesRef->getNome()[0]))
```

Eu verifico se na primeira posição do array salvo neste método está diferente de vazio, começou aparecer o erro apenas quando migrei para o Sub-dominio.

Alguém já passou por isso e que pode me ajudar?

Agradeço!!!

Comment: No erro, o que aparece a seguir ao `in /`? O erro diz qual a linha onde está o erro? O que tem a linha anterior e seguinte?

Comment: Qual versão do php usa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dois problemas, mas o problema principal é: "Qual é a versão do seu PHP?"

## Empty e expressões arbitrárias

O `empty` só aceita expressões arbritarias a partir da versão `5.5` do PHP.

Em PHP 5.5 ou superior isso é permitido:

```
if (empty(call_function()) return false;
```

Em versões anteriores, não é aceito, e gerará o seguinte erro.

> Can't use method return value in write context

## Array ou String Dereferencing em chamadas de funções ou métodos

Essa funcionalidade permite você acessar, através da captura do índice, o valor de um `array` ou `string`. Essa funcionalidade só está disponível a partir da versão 5.4 de PHP.

Por exemplo:

```
 $ClientesRef->getNome()[0];
  
 function meu_array() {
     return array(1, 2, 3);
 }

 function minha_string() {
    return 'Wallace';
 }


 meu_array()[0]; // int(1);

 minha_string()[0]; // string(W);
```

Em versões anteriores, isso gerará um erro de sintaxe.

## Como saber a versão do PHP que estou usando?

Se estiver usando ambiente de desenvolvimento Linux, basta usar o seguinte comando no terminal:

```
 php -v
```

Esse comando também funciona no Windows, mas você tem que configurar as variáveis de ambiente, para o PHP funcionar.

Também é possível fazer essa checagem rodando um script com o seguinte código:

```
 exit(PHP_VERSION);
```

Comment: poderia explicar melhor esse negocio de indice de array em função?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly adicionado!

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, já vou verificar então a versão, nem me atendei a isto.

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe curta para array foi introduzida na versão 5.4.

Em versões inferiores é emitido erro de sintaxe.

Veja: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Ainda é cedo usar o shorthand `[]` pois muitos serviços de hospedagem ainda possuem PHP inferior a versão 5.4. O mais seguro é usar `array()`.

```
// Ainda cedo usar isso, caso o seu sistema for instalado em ambientes diversos, especialmente com PHP inferior ao 5.4
$arr = [];

// use assim:
$arr = array();
```

## Array dereferencing

Isso também não é muito adequado pois é um recurso introduzido no PHP5.4

```
if(!empty($ClientesRef->getNome()[0]))
```

Para corrigir:

```
$arr = $ClientesRef->getNome();
if (!empty($arr[0])) {
    //faz os cambalacho aqui e tal
}
```

Consulte: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

<sub>nota: Caso tenha certeza de que o seu projeto nunca rodará sob um ambiente com PHP inferior ao 5.4, não precisa se preocupar e pode usar como quiser.</sub>

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, já vou verificar então a versão, nem me atendei a isto.

Answer (score 1):

O erro de sintaxe do código parece estar relacionado a versão do php.

Essa sintaxe só está disponível a partir do php5.4

```
$ClientesRef->getNome()[0]
```

Para contornar isso, crie uma nova variável e teste ela no if.

```
$nome = $ClientesRef->getNome();
if(!empty($nome[0]))
```

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, já vou verificar então a versão, nem me atendei a isto.